# window.ScrollHeight and window.ClientHeight are returning the same value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I want to calculate the scrolled percentage using javascript.But i am not able to get because of scrollHeight issue. It is not considering the hidden page size.

`Code: https://codepen.io/tmuthu/pen/jOmaKMQ`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
var topsh = document.documentElement.scrollHeight || document.body.scrollHeight;
```

with

```
var topsh = document.querySelector('.main').scrollHeight
```

and it'll work.